# Normalize ASCII to UTF-8 in R

Tags: r, regex, ascii, stringr, stringi

I have a dataframe I am trying to convert to rdf to edit in
Protege. The dataframe unfortunately has ASCII codes that are not visible when the strings are printed, most notoriously `\u0020`, which its he code for a space.

```
x <- "\u0020". 
x
> " "
```

`grepl()` works fine when searching for the pattern,
but does not return the original string when the
result is printed.

```
match <- 
grep(pattern = "\u0020", x = x, value = TRUE)
match
> " "
```

The problem is that these codes are throwing Protege off and I'm trying to normalize them to basic characters such as `\u0020` to `" "`, but I cannot find any regex that will catch these and replace them with the single non-code character. The regex pattern `[^ -~]` does not catch these values and I'm completely blind to these strings otherwise. How can I normalize any of these codes in R?

Comment: The string "\u0020" and the string " " are *identical* in R.  The parser converts that Unicode escape to a space.  There is no way to tell the difference looking at your variable `x`.  The only way to discover such things is to look at the source code.

Comment: Perhaps worth a read [utf8 vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/utf8/vignettes/utf8.html).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would just replace all unicode in the file using the `stringi` library.

Given a CSV file, `test.csv` that looks like

```
col1,col2,col3
\u0020, moretext, evenmoretext
```

First load it as a data.frame

```
> frame <- read.csv("test.txt", encoding="UTF-8")
> frame
     col1      col2          col3
1 \\u0020  moretext  evenmoretext
```

Next, find all of the occurrences that you want to replace and use `stri_unescape_unicode` to turn it into something that Protege likes.

```
> frame$col1
[1] "\\u0020"
frame$col1 <- stri_unescape_unicode(frame$col1)
> frame$col1
[1] " "
```

Once replaced, you should be able to write your csv back to disk without the unicode entries.